# Taking a Column of Output from comm Without Losing Blank Lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cut, comm

I'm trying to assemble a list of software installations per user.  I have the complete list of users in file1.txt, and the list of users with the software installed in file2.txt.  I want to end up with lines that are only in file1.txt or in both file1.txt and file2.txt, but including blank lines.  So:

file1.txt

```
bhope
bsmith
fjones
jdoe
zdirks
```

file2.txt

```
bhope
jdoe
zdirks
```

I can get partway there with `comm -2 file1.txt file2.txt`, which gives me:

```
<tab>bhope
bsmith
fjones
<tab>jdoe
<tab>zdirks
```

I want the output to be:

```
bhope
<blank line>
<blank line>
jdoe
zdirks
```

With bonus points for replacing the actual output lines with "Y"'s:

```
Y
<blank line>
<blank line>
Y
Y
```

But can't find a way to preserve the blank lines with `cut` or `awk`.

Comment: Did you not see the error message `comm: file 1 is not in sorted order
`?

Comment: `comm -2 file1.txt file2.txt | awk -f'\t' '{print $2}'`?

Comment: @Kevin, you mean `-F'\t'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have fixed the sorted problem:

```
comm -2 file1.txt file2.txt | awk -F'\t' '{print (NF==2?"y":"")}'
```

```
y


y
y
```

Comment: Sorry, I built the examples on the fly and thus I failed to hand-sort properly.  This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

this one-liner should give what you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{if($0 in a)print $0;else print ""}' file2 file1
```

see example below:

```
kent$  head file1 file2
==> file1 <==
bsmith
bhope
fjones
jdoe
zdirks

==> file2 <==
bhope
jdoe
zdirks

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{if($0 in a)print $0;else print ""}' file2 file1

bhope

jdoe
zdirks
```

and.... I didn't understand your

> bonus points

part. what are those `Y`s?

Comment: You can also `print "Y"` instead of `print $0` for the bonus points.

Comment: This works as well--sorry about the sort order in the original question.